# Not showing row in extjs Grid

Tags: grid, extjs

I currently have a filled grid.
But all of my data is in my extrabody using the rowbody feature.
This renders my actual row useless and annoying.
it leaves a white row at the top of my extrabody which i do not want.

Anybody know how to not show this?

i have tried it in css, i have tried not defining columns but then the grid is empty.

i have tried this:

```
columns: [

{
    text: 'Name',
    //dataIndex: 'name',
    height: 1,
    width: 250,
}
```

Comment: can you show a fiddle or working piece of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you described your use case I guess a [DataView](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View) would be far better fitting your requirements. I guess you can transfer nearly the whole code (with that Iam meaning the configuration and template) into it without writing to much new lines (as long as you are using templates for render the extrabody).

So is there any other reason why you have chosen a grid?

Comment: i chose a grid for the grouping feature